# how to find the first and last records of every month in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch the first and last record of every month in sql but my query give the results below and here is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT month, amount, 
       MIN(date) OVER (PARTITION BY month ORDER BY utility.month) 
FROM 
    utility;
```

**results of the query above**

| month | amount | min(date) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| February/2022 | 200 | 2022-02-02 |
| January/2022 | 1000 | 2022-01-01 |
| January/2022 | 200 | 2022-01-01 |
| March/2022 | 1000 | 2022-02-06 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `MIN()` and `MAX()` value first, turn into a subquery then join `utility` table twice to get the amount corresponding to the extracted dates, like this:

```
SELECT v.month,
       v.mindt,
       u1.amount,
       v.maxdt,
       u2.amount
   FROM
(SELECT month, 
       MIN(date) mindt, MAX(date) maxdt
FROM 
    utility
GROUP BY month) v
JOIN utility u1 ON u1.date=v.mindt
JOIN utility u2 ON u2.date=v.maxdt
;
```

That will give result something like this:

| month | mindt | amount | maxdt | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January2022 | 2022-01-02 | 250 | 2022-01-29 | 350 |
| February2022 | 2022-02-01 | 300 | 2022-02-28 | 500 |
| March2022 | 2022-03-03 | 500 | 2022-03-18 | 300 |

Or you can modify the subquery to do `UNION ALL`, join `utility` once and return all in just the original 3 columns:

```
SELECT v.month,
       v.minmaxdt,
       u.amount
   FROM
(SELECT month, 
        MIN(date) minmaxdt
    FROM utility
   GROUP BY month 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT month, 
        MAX(date) 
    FROM utility
    GROUP BY month
 ) v
JOIN utility u ON u.date=v.minmaxdt
ORDER BY v.month, v.minmaxdt;
```

That will give result something like this:

| month | minmaxdt | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| February2022 | 2022-02-01 | 300 |
| February2022 | 2022-02-28 | 500 |
| January2022 | 2022-01-02 | 250 |
| January2022 | 2022-01-29 | 350 |
| March2022 | 2022-03-03 | 500 |
| March2022 | 2022-03-18 | 300 |

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=57d8d0a0db6ff1c49edeea9809f9b1e1)

Comment: thank you very much sir it solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Try using `MIN` and `MAX` at the same time together with `GROUP BY`.

Check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp) from W3Schools.

> The MIN() function returns the smallest value of the selected column.

> The MAX() function returns the largest value of the selected column.

Try this code:
`SELECT DISTINCT month, amount, MIN(date), MAX(date) FROM utility GROUP BY month;`